# Gulp task not exit properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have the following install task :

```
gulp.task('install', ['createInfraIniFile']);

gulp.task('createAppIni', function () {

   return gulp.src('')
    .pipe(prompt.prompt([{
        type: 'input',
        name: 'version',
        message: 'Please enter the version ?'
    }], function(res){
        var config = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync('./ini/test_sample.ini', 'utf-8'));

        // Write params into app.ini file
        config.DATA.version = res.version;

        fs.writeFileSync('./ini/test.ini', ini.stringify(config));
    }));

});

gulp.task('createInfraIniFile', ['createAppIni'], function () {

   return gulp.src('')
    .pipe(prompt.prompt([{
        type: 'input',
        name: 'version',
        message: 'Please enter url'
    }], function(res){
        var config = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync('./ini/conf_sample.ini', 'utf-8'));

        // Write params into app.ini file
        config.DATA.url = res.url;

        fs.writeFileSync('./ini/conf.ini', ini.stringify(config));
    }));

});
```

This task executes the createAppIni task first and then, the createInfraIniFile. But at the end, gulp doesn't stop execution :

[image]

When i execute a single task, it works fine. Where is my mistake ?

Comment: There is no mistake in the code you've posted.

Comment: @is it possible to use writeFileAsync 2 times in 2 different tasks ?